# Oracle month year temp table

Tags: oracle, calendar

I am trying to create a month, year temp table that I can relate to in calculations, however I am having some issues. I am unable to create global temp tables due to restrictions and have to rely on the following kind of query.

```
WITH Months AS
(
SELECT LEVEL -1 AS ID
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=264
)
(SELECT 
ROWNUM AS MO_SYS_ID,
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), ID), 'YYYY'||'MM') AS MO_NM,
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), ID), 'MON') AS MO_ABBR_NM,
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), ID), 'MONTH') AS MO_FULL_NM,
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), ID), 'MM')AS MO_NBR,
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), ID), 'YYYY') AS YR_NBR 
from Months;
```

What I really need to do is have this inserted into the temp table that I can recall. I do not have any fields that I can use from other tables either unfortunately. I need it to show 264 months from 1999.

Thank you

Comment: and you can't create a (permanent) table?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I wish.

Comment: and what specifically is the problem just using `with` as you already do? is something missing?

Comment: I need to be able to join it to query, this way does not work.

Comment: Show us the query please, and then indicate what it is you are trying to achieve. Typically the most efficient way to do this is to supply **sample data** and **expected results** (ideally as DDL but parsable text is ok) `don't use images of data` try just adding text into the question like you have with the query.

Comment: Right now all I need is for this date data to sit in a temp table, that is all.

Comment: if you cannot make the `with` table work, how is using a temp table built from the same query going to be any different? trying to help requires understanding the problem. You aren't producing any date columns, just to_char() string columns, is this the core issue?

Comment: Yes this is the core issue. Thank you for taking your time to get a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why do you create 5 different columns for basically the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate a date column within the table expression, like this:

```
WITH Months AS (
    SELECT LEVEL -1 AS ID, ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), LEVEL -1) as dt
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=264
    )
SELECT *
from Months
```

If you are attempting to create date ranges, you could do this:

```
WITH Months AS (
    SELECT LEVEL -1 AS ID
         , ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), LEVEL -1) as start_dt
         , ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1999', 'DD/MM/YY'), LEVEL ) as end_dt
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=264
    )
SELECT *
from yourtable t
inner join Months m on t.somecol >= m.start_dt and  t.somecol < m.end_dt
```

Comment: This is great not only have you answered my question you have shown me where I went wrong originally. I really appreciate your help, thank you so much.

Comment: I did not see your second part. What if I had just one date field in the months but I had another table that had members with start dates and end dates. Trying to see if the months dates fell within the members start and end dates?